# Stream Analytics, grabbing value if happened once over time

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

Here is an example of a query with what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
WITH IoTData AS
( SELECT *,
    CAST(iothub.time AS datetime) AS time,
    TRY_CAST(iothub.value AS float) AS value,
    ref.AssetSignalTag AS assetsignaltag

    FROM iothub TIMESTAMP BY iothub.time

    JOIN masterdatasql ref 
    ON ref.[ConnectionString] = iothub.id
    WHERE iothub.value IS NOT NULL
),

HISTORY AS ( 
SELECT assetsignaltag,
value,
COUNT(*) AS Count
CASE
 WHEN value = 1 THEN 1
 ELSE 0
END AS ConditionResult

FROM IoTData
   
GROUP BY assetsignaltag, SlidingWindow(minute, 30), value
)


SELECT
    time,
    value,
    assetsignaltag,
    HISTORY.ConditionResult,
    HISTORY.Count 

INTO eventhub
FROM IoTData 
JOIN HISTORY
ON HISTORY.assetsignaltag = IoTData.assetsignaltag
AND DATEDIFF(minute, IoTData, HISTORY) = 10
WHERE HISTORY.ConditionResult = 1
AND MAX(HISTORY.Count) OVER (PARTITION BY IoTData.assetsignaltag LIMIT DURATION (minute, 10)) = 1

/* Here is where I run into issues, because I'm not sure how to grab the value of 'over last 10 minutes if there was only 1 value'.

Also tried AND HISTORY.Count = 1 which makes more sense to me since I'm already defining the time of 10 minutes in the DATEDIFF above, but I'm not sure that the datetime function does what I think it does.

 */
```

The issue is this will be accepted in stream analytics syntax wise, but won't function. I am trying to essentially make a datapoint that is 'noisy' less noisy. We don't really care if it flips to 1 to 0 to 1 to 0 to 1 within 2 minutes, but if it flips to 1 and stays there for 10 minutes, we would like it to go into the eventhub, which triggers an alert.

Let me know if I can clarify anything on this, or if I should try anything in particular.

Comment: have you tried ISFRIST? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/isfirst-azure-stream-analytics

Comment: @silent wouldn't that just grab the first value from the 10 minute window and disregard if there are values that come after? Looking to only grab if the 1 entry has come in for the datapoint over the 10 minutes

Comment: hm maybe then more a case for LAG https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/lag-azure-stream-analytics This allows you to compare whether a value has changed compared to the last time it was sent. does that fit your case more?

Comment: @silent That seems closer to the answer, but I'm a little confused on how I'd make the syntax work to my favor. Something like 

LAG(IoTData.value,1,'ALERT') OVER (PARTITION BY IoTData.AssetSignalTag LIMIT DURATION(minute,10)) AS AlertResult

I'm not sure if this works like how I think it does. It seems like LAG is looking for the previous value. Will it only go back as long as there's a value in that window? If there isn't can I then send a trigger value? My goal is to drop everything if there are two events that happen with the same assetsignaltag in the same 10 minute sliding window

Comment: LAG looks at all events in your LIMIT time range. LAST only looks at the previous event https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/last-azure-stream-analytics

Comment: Been doing a bit of testing with this, I don't think LAG fits what the condition is either. Issue is that it would require a new value coming in. What I'm trying to have happen is if a value comes in with a value of 1, meeting the condition on line 18 of my query above, it should start a 10 minute timer. If no value comes in after that we want it to get submitted to the event hub queue. I tried COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY IoTData.assetsignaltag LIMIT DURATION(minute,10)) = 1 as a select statement with a GROUP BY assetsignaltag, SlidingWindow(minute,10), but I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I may not fully understand the computation you want to do, but seems like you can skip the join and just use LAG for that.

The HISTORY step creates a stream of "for each event in IoTData, look back 30 minutes and count number of event per assetsignaltag and a 1 or 0 value".

If you want to only get such results when the number of events is exactly 1 in the last 10 minute you can:

```
SELECT *
FROM HISTORY
WHERE Count() OVER (LIMIT DURATION(minute, 10)) = 1
```